# WPF - Canvas Background Not Displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, background, wpf-controls, imagebrush

I am a complete newbie to WPF.  I've been working on a personal project for about 2 weeks.  It's been coming along, and suddenly hit a roadblock.  Everything was working perfect until I shifted some things around.

It's basically a satellite map as the canvas background, so that I can overlay geometry on it.  The image is 10000x10000, and has not changed.  It's added as a resource and... funny enough, shows up in the Visual Basic xaml designer.

The local:ZoomBorder class zooms/pans the viewbox/canvas.  I did not post the code because it has not been touched since it last worked.

Geometry is being added to the canvas correctly.

I moved around some dimensions, as far as the grid goes.  Like adding margins and such, but can't get it back to displaying the imagebrush background, no matter what I do.

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Temp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="930" Width="1100" PreviewKeyDown="mapBorder_PreviewKeyDown">
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="210" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
        <StackPanel Name="stackPanel" />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="mapBorder" Background="Gray" Margin="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" ClipToBounds="True">
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas Name="mapGrid" Height="10000" Width="10000">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="map.jpg"/>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </local:ZoomBorder>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="80" Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="Start Refresh" Width="80" Click="buttonStartRefresh" />
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="80" Margin="110,0,0,0" Content="Stop Refresh" Width="80" Click="buttonStopRefresh" />
    <CheckBox Name="Advanced" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Label Margin="0,-5,0,0">Advanced</Label>
    </CheckBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: To check whether your executable is able to find the image, you could include the absolute path to the image in `ImageSource` and see if it shows up.

Comment: The image is being added to the executable (bigger size), and I've also tried the absolute path :(

Comment: be sure your `map.jpg` is added as a `Resource` or at least a `Content`. To check it, right click on the image under the project treeview, select Properties, you'll see the current setting in ***Build Action***.

Comment: It's added as a resource. :(

Comment: Update: So, when I debug the program... the background shows. When I build, it doesn't. Also, if I change the background to a color, it works fine, to where the image should be.